# Google Sheet ArrayFormula in Excel 365

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, office365

Hi I am using google sheet for my daily calculation and I have used ArrayFormula which is working fine. Now, I want to shift my data from Google Sheet to Office 365 Excel. I tried the same formula there but it's not working.

| Users | Days Worked |
| --- | --- |
| Bas | 10 |
| Walter | 10 |
| Bas | 10 |
| Walter | 15 |
| James | 5 |
| James | 10 |

Formula Used

> ={unique(A18:A25),ArrayFormula(sumif(A18:A25,unique(A18:A25),B18:B25))}

**End Result**

| Users | Days Worked |
| --- | --- |
| Bas | 20 |
| Walter | 25 |
| James | 15 |

In Google Sheet is this formula is filtering unique values and gives the sum of related values.
I tried the same method but it's not working. Please suggest any post or video where can I find the same methodology if possible. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you checked to see if all the functions that you use in googlesheets exist in Excel? Then, if they do that all the arguments are in the same places and they work identically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the curly bracket notation in the same way in Excel but there is a workaround using Choose to combine two arrays:

```
=CHOOSE({1,2},UNIQUE(A18:A25),SUMIF(A18:A25,UNIQUE(A18:A25),B18:B25))
```

However, in both Google sheets and Excel you will notice an extra row corresponding to the blank cells in the range A18:A25, so you will need to use filter as well:

```
=CHOOSE({1,2},UNIQUE(FILTER(A18:A25,A18:A25<>"")),SUMIF(A18:A25,UNIQUE(FILTER(A18:A25,A18:A25<>"")),B18:B25))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You so much, I never heard about choose function. I will learn more about it. Thanks again.